# Stripping CData Tags XML Perl

Tags: xml, perl, cdata

In PHP you could simply strip off CDATA tags in XML by doing the following:

```
simplexml_load_string($string, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

I was wondering how could I do this in Perl using `XML::Bare` or any other module?

My client tends to send an xml like this:

```
<msg t='sys'><body action='login' r='0'><login z='w1'><nick><![CDATA[Test]]></nick><pword><![CDATA[4c24a5558542bf35cca54d8749c78de6]]></pword></login></body></msg>
```

Using XML::Bare I would parse it like this:

```
$string = "<msg t='sys'><body action='login' r='0'><login z='w1'><nick><![CDATA[Test]]></nick><pword><![CDATA[4c24a5558542bf35cca54d8749c78de6]]></pword></login></body></msg>";
$strXML = XML::Bare->new('text' => $string)->parse;
say $strXML->{msg}->{body}->{login}->{nick}->{value};
```

and it works but I'd like to strip off the cdata tags to prevent an sql injection in my server. Does anyone know how I can go about doing this? I've searched all over the web for a solution and haven't been able to find one.

Comment: What is your expected output from that example XML?

Comment: [XML::Bare says that it will strip](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Bare#Parsing-Limitations-Features) unneeded CDATA...

Comment: I would basically want an xml parsed without cdata

Comment: like this for example: `<msg t='sys'><body action='login' r='0'><login z='w1'><nick>Test</nick><pword>4c24a5558542bf35cca54d8749c78de6</pword></login></body></msg>`

Comment: And how is that better than with cdata? If the data contained characters that need escaping the file will not be valid. How is that going to help stop sql injection? Maybe you should instead consider the way you treat incoming data in general.

Comment: Re "*I'd like to strip off the cdata tags to prevent an sql injection in my server*", what??? One has nothing to do with the other.

Comment: Are you trying to strip CDATA tags when writing XML? Or do you just want them to be transparent when reading the XML. The latter should be the default for all parsers!!! It definitely is for XML::LibXML.

Comment: It's far from clear what the *SimpleXML* `LIBXML_NOCDATA` actually does. [The documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php) says just *"Merge CDATA as text nodes"*, and I hope that it would encode markup characters as character entities at the same time, but that isn't assured. The *only difference* between a CDATA node and an ordinary text node is that the contents may include markup characters. In effect it temporarily changes the markup to just `]]>` which marks the end of the CDATA section. Anything you can express wihin a CDATA node may be written in an ordinary text node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example the following:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

#the input xml
my $str = q{<msg t='sys'><body action='login' r='0'><login z='w1'><nick><![CDATA[Test]]></nick><pword><![CDATA[4c24a5558542bf35cca54d8749c78de6]]></pword></login></body></msg>};

#the parsing
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(
    string => $str,
    no_cdata => 1,  #strip CDATA
);

#nice-print the parsed xml
say $dom->toString(2);

#print the "nick" and pword
say "the nick  is ==", $dom->find( '//nick' )->string_value, "==";
say "the pword is ==", $dom->find( '//pword' )->string_value, "==";
```

prints the original XML without the CDATA, such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<msg t="sys">
  <body action="login" r="0">
    <login z="w1">
      <nick>Test</nick>
      <pword>4c24a5558542bf35cca54d8749c78de6</pword>
    </login>
  </body>
</msg>

the nick  is ==Test==
the pword is ==4c24a5558542bf35cca54d8749c78de6==
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `HTML::Parser` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::Parser;

my $xml = <<XML;
<msg t='sys'><body action='login' r='0'><login z='w1'><nick><![CDATA[Test]]></nick><pword><![CDATA[4c24a5558542bf35cca54d8749c78de6]]></pword></login></body></msg>
XML

my $parsed_xml;

HTML::Parser->new(default_h => [ sub { $parsed_xml .= shift }, 'text' ],
    xml_mode => 1,
    marked_sections => 1,
  )->parse($xml) or die $!;

print $parsed_xml;
```

`marked_sections` parameter causes the parser to return the contents of `CDATA` section as `text`, which then is concatenated to the `$parsed_xml` variable.

Comment: What I want to do is to remove the cdata tags but conserve the values in it like the xml I posted in the comments above

Comment: I've updated the script to meet your requirements @Lucas